# On polymorphic associations, is it possible to pull in multiple source types on one has_many through query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, polymorphic-associations

When dealing with polymorphic associations, is it possible to have a has_many through query that pulls in ALL available source_types?

My understanding so far is that each source type needs its own query method, as I show here in the Image model

**image.rb**

```
has_many :image_tags
has_many :tags, through: :image_tags, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Tag'
has_many :people, through: :image_tags, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Person'
has_many :businesses, through: :image_tags, source: :taggable, source_type: 'Business'
...
```

**tag.rb**

```
has_many :image_tags, as: :taggable
has_many :images, through: :image_tags
```

**image_tag.rb**

```
belongs_to :image
belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true

def build_taggable(params)
  self.taggable = taggable_type.constantize.new(params)
end
```

What I'd like to be able to do, however, is create one query method that pulls in all associated records regardless of what source_type they might belong to.

Just thinking out loud, would that likely involve creating some sort of raw SQL join that acts directly on the ImageTags table? Or is there a more Railsy/ActiveRecordy way of approaching it?

---

**UPDATE 20200319:**

I've since found a way to aggregate the individual methods together, but this still requires the creation of unique methods.

```
def taggables 
  tags + people + businesses
end
```

This allows for something like

```
i = Image.first
i.crops.map(&:taggables)
```

Still not quite an answer, but it's a temporary workaround in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to get any association that is attached to **image_tag**:

```
# get all images with all associations
imgs = Image.includes(image_tags: :taggable)

# to get value polymorphic association regardless of it's source
# taggable may be tags, people or businesses
poly_assoc = imgs.first.taggable # associaiton of first record
# to get the association type
pp pol_assoc.to_s.class.to_s
```

Comment: Hello @Shiko, thank you for your help! For some reason, the second method call `imgs.first.taggable` is returning  a `NoMethodError, undefined method 'taggable' for <Image>`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I've updated my original post with a temporary workaround in-case that helps give you or anyone else some ideas on a possible solution.